# How to make the JavaFX ScrollPane fill the SWT composite all the time, even the SWT Form is resized

Tags: javafx, swt

I have a JavaFX ScrollPane embedded inside a SWT composite, and the composite is filled in side a SWT Form. How to make the JavaFX ScrollPane fill the SWT composite all the time, even the SWT Form is resized.

Here is a example how I use a FXCanvas to hold the JavaFX content:

```
  public Control createContents(Composite parent) {
    final Composite composite = (Composite) super.createContents(parent);
    composite.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    // Create a JavaFX canvas
    final FXCanvas fxCanvas = new FXCanvas(composite, SWT.NONE);
    /* Create a JavaFX Group node */
    Group group = new Group();
    start(group);
    fxCanvas.setScene(scene);
    return composite;
}

public void start(final Group stage) {
        Parent zoomPane = createZoomPane(group);
        stage.getChildren().add(zoomPane);
}

private Parent createZoomPane(final Group group) {
        final double SCALE_DELTA = 1.1;
        final StackPane zoomPane = new StackPane();
        zoomPane.getChildren().add(group);

        scroller = new ScrollPane();
        final Group scrollContent = new Group(zoomPane);
        scroller.setContent(scrollContent);
        return scroller;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? May be unrelated to your question unless I see a MCVE, but you shouldn't use `Group` if you want the component to auto-size in JavaFX.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The issue is because I created a Group as the root and add it to the Scene, I should just create a VBox as the root and add it to the Scene.

Answer (score 0):

After my experiment, I found the answer by myself, it's a common issue for JavaFx actually, not related with SWT.

The reason is I created a Group as the root and add it to the Scene, I should just create a VBox as the root and add it to the Scene.